# php curl post not sending data

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send POST data:

```
$url ="https://server:510/1/auth/";

$data = array(
      "USERNAME" => "user",
      "PASSWORD" => "password"
 );

$str_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array('Content-Type:application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($str_data))
); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_data);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTREDIR,3);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
print_r($response);
```

and the server response is(result of verbose): 
"you haven't sent any credentials"

```
> POST /1/auth/ HTTP/1.1
Host: server:port
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 39
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 18:53:52 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.8
< Content-Length: 73
< Content-Type: application/json
<
```

it seems like i am not sending post data. what am i missing?

i have noticed that in chrome debugger, under network, the request is sent as a GET....

below is the documentation from server vendor:

For example, suppose your server is hosted at 10.211.55.3. To request a session token provide your username and password as POSTING variables in the following URL (note the use of the /1/, which is the API version number):

```
https://10.211.55.3/1/auth
USERNAME  = 'api@domain.com'
PASSWORD  = 'Tester01'
```

thats it :(

Comment: You cannot see in the browser (be it Chrome or any other) what happens in the code that runs on the server.

Comment: sure, but i can see that the method was "GET" and not "POST".  true?

Comment: You can see in the browser what the browser communicates with the server. I suppose you run on the server the PHP code you posted. The code uses `curl` to connect to another server and send an HTTP request to it. The browser is not involved in any way in this second connection and has no idea about it. It cannot see how your code connects to the other server. All it can see is the output of your script. And that output displays (because of `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`) that the request to the second server was done using `POST`. The problem is probably the content type, not the method.

Comment: does this line "< Content-Type: application/json"  in the response from server tell me it is requiring json?

Comment: Nope. It only says that the response is encoded as `JSON`. The documentation probably says how you should format the request.

Comment: added the very minimal documentation i am working from.....

Comment: Well, it doesn't say anything about `JSON`, right? In this case remove the `Content-Type` header (`curl` takes care of it) and use `http_build_query($data)` and not `json_encode()` to prepare the data you send.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url ="https://server:510/1/auth/";
$data = array(
      "username" => "username",
      "password" => "password"
 );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override:'POST','Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Length: ' .     strlen(http_build_query($data))));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

this worked.

Comment: This couldn't have worked. The line with the curl header has a syntax error